# Attributes showing as numbers on front end

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, custom-attributes

I have added a new drop-down attribute called features to products.

It is basically a list of options that I want to show on the front end. I have used this code to my list.phtml file for get option values:

```
<?php echo $_product->getfeatures() ?>
```

But it will display as number instead of text on fronted.

How I can display drop down option value as text ?

The below picture shows 2 features but instead of text it shows as numbers. Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: The piece of code I added was:

Comment: <?php echo $_product->getfeatures() ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use:

```
<?php echo $_product->getFeatures();?>
```

**it will return option value of attribute like 18,19**

if you use:

```
<?php $_product->getAttributeText('features');?>
```

**it will return an Array**

so first get an Array and convert it to String

```
<?php $features = $_product->getAttributeText('features');?> 
<?php echo implode(",", $features) ;?>
```

**It will display your Text**

Answer (score 0):

Within either `catalog/product/view.phtml` or `catalog/product/list.html` you can use this to output the attribute text:

```
echo $_product->getAttributeText('features');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get your selected options like:

> $x = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('your_attribute_code');

and then get the values of your selected options:

> $x->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display attribute option value then you should write code like this

```
<?php $_product->getAttributeText('features');?>
```

insted of

```
<?php echo $_product->getFeatures();?>
```